# Merging two variables to match a nesting array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to match the name  of the array with the name of a nesting array inside. `Y` has many, many nesting arrays. I gave two as an example. Also, `i` always has a random nesting array name. In this example, `i` is equal to `car`.

```js
var y = {car:['honda','ford'],color:['red','green']/*,...More here*/};
    i = 'car'; //This value can change to either 'car', or 'color', etc...
    var x = y + i;
    console.log(x);
```

I need to get the value of `x` to become `y.car`, which will log `["honda", "ford"]`. Instead, `x` logs `[object Object]car`. How do I get `x`, `var x = y + i`, to return `["honda", "ford"]` instead?

**EDIT:**

Yes, but `x = y[i]` is not working in my for loop.

```
    for (i = 0; y.length > i; i++) {
        console.log(y[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Try `x = y[i]` instead.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var y = {car:['honda','ford'],color:['red','green']/*,...More here*/};
var keys = Object.keys(y);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log(y[keys[i]]);
}
```

Comment: What if I need it to be color, or some other array? The name is going to be random.

Comment: @Ackados explain what you mean.